# Custom Attribute Store to query all groups of a person

Tags: c#, active-directory, adfs

can somebody help me with my code? I need a Custom Attribute store that query all groups of a person.

I don't know how to get the username of the person accessing the relying party.

My code goes like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore;
using System.IdentityModel;


namespace GroupClaimAttributeStore
{
    public class GroupClaimStore : IAttributeStore
    {
        public IAsyncResult BeginExecuteQuery(string query, string[] parameters, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("uk.svc.com") { AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure, Path = "LDAP://OU=staffusers,DC=leeds-art,DC=ac,DC=uk" });
            // get username
            string username = string.Empty;
            // set filter
            search.Filter = "(cn=" + username + ")";

            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");

            List<string> outputValue = new List<string>();

            if (result != null)
            {
                ResultPropertyCollection fields = result.Properties;
                var groups = fields["memberOf"];
                foreach (var group in groups)
                {
                    outputValue.Add(group.ToString());
                }
            }

            TypedAsyncResult<string[]> asyncResult = new TypedAsyncResult<string[]>(callback, state);
            asyncResult.Complete(outputValue.ToArray(), false);
            return asyncResult;
        }

        public string[][] EndExecuteQuery(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            return TypedAsyncResult<string[][]>.End(result);
        }

        public void Initialize(Dictionary<string, string> config)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an LDAP rule mapping "Token Groups - Unqualified Names" to "Roles".

Otherwise, there is no AD attribute called "username". You probably need "sAMAccountName".